# What is the proper way to extend the Dict class?

Tags: python, dictionary, extend

I want to implement two different dictionaries with a predefined set of valid keys. Also, one dictionary contains the other.

```
class Otherdict (dict):

    _keys = ['A','B']

    def __init__(self):
        for key in self._keys:
            self[key] = None

    def populateDict(self):
        self['B'] = 10
        self['A'] = 12

class MyDict(dict):

    _keys = ['R','ED']

    def __init__(self):
        for key in self._keys:
            self[key] = None

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self._keys:
            raise Exception("'" + key + "'" + " is not a valid key")
        dict.__getitem__(self,key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in self._keys:
            raise Exception("'" + key + "'" + " is not a valid key")
        dict.__setitem__(self,key,value)

    def populateDict(self):
        d = Otherdict()
        d.populateDict()
        self['R'] = 3
        self['ED'] = d


a = MyDict()
a.populateDict()
print a['ED'].__class__    #prints <type 'NoneType'>
```

The problem is that for some reason I cannot access the dictionary located under the 'ED' key. What am I doing wrong here?

I've also noticed that if I remove the `__getitem__()` method, the code works properly

Comment: Do you need to do the `if key not in self._keys:` check? Can't you just call `dict.__getitem__` and let the exception propagate?

Comment: I would just recommend you use an exception type that is a bit more specific than `Exception`; it will make catching exceptions easier.

Comment: A slight error with huge impact, easy to spot. Nevertheless no reason for -1, IMHO.

Comment: You're are both right, i'll make the changes, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__getitem__` must return a value:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key not in self._keys:
        raise Exception("'" + key + "'" + " is not a valid key")
    return dict.__getitem__(self,key)
```

If there is no explicit return statement, Python functions return None by default.

Comment: thanks, it works! It looks obvious now that i know what the problem was, such a beginner's mistake!

Answer (score 3):

Use `return` in `def __getitem__(self, key)`  :  `return dict.__getitem__(self,key)`,

the code runs properly when you remove `__getitem__` it's because it then accesses `__getitem__` from parent classes(which is `dict` in this case).